# Realtime client1 to server to client2 communication

Tags: node.js, server, client

I try to make realtime events/communication between my clients, through my server of course.

It is a bit like Facebook friend invitation and notification system, someone send you a friend request, and on your end you see that you have a new invitation without to have to refresh the page.

How does this work ? Is it simply the client that asks the server at some time interval if he has new events to display? Or is it a socket based system where the client would have something like a listening socket waiting for the server to notify him when he has something new to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches will work but hitting an endpoint for data the server wants to push to the client is generally frowned upon, so your answer: websockets.

Edit: It’d also be easier to add more stuff that is sent from server to the client later.